# Update DOM using jQuery without chaining current object

Tags: jquery

I often find myself selecting an element, going down the DOM to update some html/text/etc, and then going back up the DOM to do something with the element.

Without doing either of the following, is there a clean way of doing so?

```
$('#foo').clone(true).children('a.bar').text('bla').parent().appendTo(blabla);

var myElem=$('#foo').clone(true);
myElem.children('a.bar').text('bla');
myElem.appendTo(blabla);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for jQuery's [.end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/). It allows you to pop the last added set of elements off the stack.

```js
$("p")
  .find("span")
  .end()
  .css("border", "2px red solid");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Hello</span>, how are you?</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nit,  Never yet used `end()`, and will give it a try.  Better than my use of `parent()` I suspect.  Ideally, I wouldn't even need to use `end()`, and would just update some DOM using some madeup method like `$('#foo').clone(true).text_update('a.bar','bla').appendTo(blabla);`  That being said, I am sure I could created such a method, but wish to stick with standard jQuery methods.  Thanks